# Is it correct to say that conformal mappings (not just the class of linear transformations) preserve orientation?

Tags: complex-analysis, conformal-geometry, mobius-transformation

We know that conformal mappings preserve angles and orientation of any two intersecting curves in the z-plane.

Is this fact alone enough to conclude that the region (domain?) to the right of some clockwise-oriented closed curve will again be to the right of the image curve in the w-plane?

This would be as convenient as symmetry arguments of, say, LFTs, but I am not used to using orientation-preserving arguments, so I just wanted to be sure.

Thanks,

Comment: no. take any holomorphic map $f,$ then switch to $\bar{f},$ it is still conformal. For example, $\bar{z}$ is a conformal map, it just reflects across the real axis

Comment: Maybe your book always uses the word conformal to mean holomorphic; I don't know.

Comment: Great example @WillJagy.  So, what if I now said that the mapping is holomorphic?  Does this stronger assumption allow me to claim that the mapping is orientation-preserving?  (Also, I was indeed using conformal and holomorphic interchangeably -- a big mistake, so thanks so much for pointing that out ... )